# React Express Routing works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I developed an app that uses a router file **feedback.router.js**. I've set up the server to import this router file and use it for `'/feedback'` requests.

I use various GET, POST, DELETE, PUT routes to communicate with the database.  Locally, my app axios requests are routed properly and are integrating with my database correctly. On my server.js file, I've read other questions and implemented what I think express should be serving for the production version. When I run the app on Heroku, the response that I receive from any axios request appears to be the HTML file which indicates that the route is not recognized, but I'm having no luck determining the error. I believe that I set up the database correctly for Heroku, although it's possible the problem lies there.

One indirect problem that this has highlighted is that I have no idea how to troubleshoot these types of requests once deployed on Heroku. I've connected it with my repository on Github, and can't find any "server terminal" to assist in bug hunting. Any advice on how to approach this troubleshooting with Heroku is very much welcome.

UPDATE to include Heroku logs for a GET and POST request:

> 2018-11-04T03:20:11.564616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
>   path="/feedback" host=prime-feedback-app.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=65732134-d050-4f82-ab08-9d0764266cb3 fwd="73.242.14.56"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2377
>   protocol=https
>
> 2018-11-04T03:21:05.866976+00:00 heroku[router]:
>   at=info method=GET path="/feedback"
>   host=prime-feedback-app.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=6b1b7341-5dbf-443d-bff4-e0a6e3080e51 fwd="73.242.14.56"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2377
>   protocol=https

I've included what files I think might be helpful.

**File Structure** (asterisks indicate folders)

```
feedback-app
    **build**
    **public**
    **server**
        **modules**
             pool.js
        **routes**
             feedback.router.js
        server.js
    **src**
        **components**
             ...
        index.js
        registerServiceWorker.js
     data.sql
     package.json
     package-lock.json
```

**example of my axios request:**

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/feedback'
}).then((response) => {
    console.log('response:',response);
    this.setState({
        display: 'all',
        feedback: response.data
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error',error);
})
```

**server.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const path = require('path');
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    const feedbackRouter = require('./routes/feedback.router');

    /** ---------- MIDDLEWARE ---------- **/
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // needed for angular requests
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        // Exprees will serve up production assets
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

        // Express serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize route
        app.get('*', (req, res) => {
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
        });
    }

    /** ---------- EXPRESS ROUTES ---------- **/
    app.use('/feedback', feedbackRouter);

    /** ---------- START SERVER ---------- **/
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log('Listening on port: ', PORT);
    });
```

**pool.js**

```
const pg = require('pg');
const url = require('url');
let config = {};

if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    // Heroku gives a url, not a connection object
    // https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool
    let params = url.parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
    let auth = params.auth.split(':');

    config = {
        user: auth[0],
        password: auth[1],
        host: params.hostname,
        port: params.port,
        database: params.pathname.split('/')[1],
        ssl: true, // heroku requires ssl to be true
        max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
    };

} else {
    // only change the things on the right side of the ||
    config = {
        user: process.env.PG_USER || null, //env var: PGUSER
        password: process.env.DATABASE_SECRET || null, //env var: PGPASSWORD
        host: process.env.DATABASE_SERVER || 'localhost', // Server hosting the postgres database
        port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT || 5432, //env var: PGPORT
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME || 'prime_feedback', //env var: PGDATABASE or the name of your database (e.g. database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME || 'koala_holla',)
        max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
    };
}

module.exports = new pg.Pool(config);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-reflection-board",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.4.1",
    "node": "10.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "pg": "^7.4.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-progressbar": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "react-swal": "^3.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "serve": "^10.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "client": "react-scripts start",
    "server": "nodemon --watch server server/server.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**feedback.router.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const pool = require('../modules/pool');

    // GET feedback
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        // Request all entered feedback and return them
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM feedback ORDER BY id DESC;')
            .then((result) => {
                res.send(result.rows);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error GET /api/feedback', error);
                res.sendStatus(500);  
        });
    })

    // GET feedback
    router.get('/flagged', (req, res) => {
        // Request all entered feedback and return them
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE flagged = true ORDER BY id DESC;')
            .then((result) => {
                res.send(result.rows);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error GET /api/feedback/flagged', error);
                res.sendStatus(500);  
        });
    })

    // POST new feedback entry
    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        const client = await pool.connect();

        try {
            const {
                feeling,
                understanding,
                support,
                comments,
                flagged
            } = req.body;
            await client.query('BEGIN')
            const orderInsertResults = await client.query(`INSERT INTO feedback ("feeling","understanding","support","comments","flagged")
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);`, [feeling, understanding, support, comments, flagged]);

            await client.query('COMMIT')
            res.sendStatus(201);
        } catch (error) {
            await client.query('ROLLBACK')
            console.log('Error post /api/feedback', error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        } finally {
            client.release()
        }
    });

    // DELETE a feedback entry
    router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
        pool.query('DELETE FROM feedback WHERE id=$1', [req.params.id]).then((result) => {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error delete /api/feedback', error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        })
    });

    // PUT / update a feedback entry
    router.put('/:id', (req,res) => {
        let feedbackId = req.params.id;
        let updatedFlagStatus = req.body.updatedFlagStatus;
        console.log('to update flag of item',feedbackId,'to',updatedFlagStatus);
        const sqlText = `UPDATE feedback SET flagged = $2 WHERE id=$1`;
        console.log('sqlText:',sqlText);
        pool.query(sqlText,[feedbackId, updatedFlagStatus])
            .then( (result) => {
                console.log('successfully updated flag status', result);
                res.sendStatus(200);
            })
            .catch( (error) => {
                console.log('error updating flag status', error);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            })
    })

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're using `FeedbackRouter` to resolve requests under the `/api/feedback` URL, are you sure your axios code shouldn't be pointing to `/api/feedback`?

Comment: Oops. One of the "fixes" I tried was changing the route from '/api/feedback' to just '/feedback'. I missed an instance here. I've fixed it and re-deployed it, but it's still returning the html. Thanks for the catch though!

Comment: Try putting your `feedbackRouter` above if statement...

Comment: @Ashley which HTML you get as the response?

Comment: @Suryan I made that adjustment and it showed that it was submitting for some time and then returned the html file. This makes me think that perhaps I didn't set up the pool correctly for Heroku.

Comment: Actually in production mode all of your routes are caught by `app.get('*')` and it won't let routes to go further down

Comment: @Davo I believe it's the index file from the build.

Comment: @Suryan That's good to know. I'll keep it above the if statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use Express to serve a React + ReactRouter app you will face this situation where Express routing and React Router "conflict".

On production environments your Express server will **"serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize route"**, so when you're requesting `/feedback` the first match is the line `app.get('*'...`, that's why your Ajax request is actually returning the index.html file.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Exprees will serve up production assets
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

    // Express serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize route
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

/** ---------- EXPRESS ROUTES ---------- **/
app.use('/feedback', feedbackRouter);
```

Place your `app.use('/feedback', feedbackRouter);` line at the beginign and it should work.

Now, you should totally install "Heroku Toolbelt" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli so you can run `heroku logs -t` on your terminal to be able to debug your serverside code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've shifted the `app.use('/feedback',feedbackRouter);` line above and it's still returning the HTML file. I'll check out "Heroku Toolbelt"!

Comment: I got the logs using the toolbelt and have updated my question to include them. The toolbelt was what I was looking for! On that note though, I'm confused on how to interpret the logs.

Comment: Cool that Toolbelt is working for you ;) it's really useful, if you put `console.log()` in your code you will see it in your terminal. The logs are a mix of Router and App logs. What happens when you visit your_app/feedback on the browser?